# Extract text between html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to extract text between html tags? For example, if I had the names of cities in California, each listed separately within paragraph tags, could I print out only the text that appears inside the paragraph tags?

```
<div class="cities">
    <div><p>Los Angeles</p><h5>Description</h5></div>
    <div><p>San Francisco</p><h5>Description</h5></div>
    <div><p>San Diego</p><h5>Description</h5></div>
    <div><p>Santa Barbara</p><h5>Description</h5></div>
    <div><p>Davis</p><h5>Description</h5></div>
    <div><p>San Jose</p><h5>Description</h5></div>
</div>
```

I want to target all of the cities in the paragraph tags but not the descriptions in the h5 tags. The expected output would be:

Los Angeles
San Francisco 
San Diego
Santa Barbara
Davis 
San Jose

Comment: the answer is Yes,  one way using .text()-- http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: which p tag you want to get ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `map()` function you can get all the text in `p` like following.

```js
var cities = $('.cities p').map(function () {
    return $(this).text();
}).get().join();

$('.show').html(cities)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cities">
    <div><p>Los Angeles</p><h5>Description</h5></div>
    <div><p>San Francisco</p><h5>Description</h5></div>
    <div><p>San Diego</p><h5>Description</h5></div>
    <div><p>Santa Barbara</p><h5>Description</h5></div>
    <div><p>Davis</p><h5>Description</h5></div>
    <div><p>San Jose</p><h5>Description</h5></div>
</div> 

<h3>All cities</h3>
<div class="show"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use jQuery to extract text by calling the `text()` function on the jQuery element(s).

```
$(selector).text()
```

or you may do it with regular JS with the `textContent` attribute

```
element.textContent
```

Answer (score 1):

Use selector `$(".cities p")` , `$.map()` , `.textContent` , which returns an array. To convert the returned array into a single string containing all items of the array, you could use `Array.prototype.join(/* delimiter */)`

```js
var cities = $.map($(".cities p"), function(el) {
  return el.textContent
});

console.log(cities, cities.join(" "))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="cities">
<div><p>Los Angeles</p><h5>Description</h5></div>
<div><p>San Francisco</p><h5>Description</h5></div>
<div><p>San Diego</p><h5>Description</h5></div>
<div><p>Santa Barbara</p><h5>Description</h5></div>
<div><p>Davis</p><h5>Description</h5></div>
<div><p>San Jose</p><h5>Description</h5></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to print it out so "Description" (content between h5 tags) is not printed out along with it?

Comment: Do you want to remove "Description" from existing `html` ? If yes, you can use `$(".cites h5").hide()` to not display the `h5` elements, or `$(".cities h5").remove()` to remove the elements from the document

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am looking to achieve. Say the paragraph tag was in a div that had many other elements <a> , <img>, etc, and I just wanted the <p>content from each div.

Comment: @MahmudAdam  You can use `$(".cites h5").hide()` to set the `h5` elements `display` to `none` ; or `$(".cities h5").remove()` to remove the elements from the document; see https://jsfiddle.net/s01vv7sc/

Answer (score 1):

Using the selector to access the item and the `html` method extracts the value from the element. It `html` method can also be used to set the value or content of that element:

```
$('.cities >:nth-child(1)').html()
```

The code above will extract the first element, you can interpolate for the oterh elements

Answer (score 0):

using jquery , this can be achieved as:

```
$(".cities").find("p").text();
```

OR for taking one at a time

```
$(".cities p").each(function() {
      var my_cities = $(this).text();
    });
```